# Is it possible to configure Fabric's HttpRequestFactory to use a proxy server

Tags: google-fabric

Good day

I would like to know if it is possible to configure fabric to use a proxy server for it's communication to it's servers?

I have been tasked with routing all our mobile application traffic through a proxy server we have set up. The reason for this is because of the high data charge in our country. We have arranged with our service providers to bill us for all traffic to this proxy, and not our customers.

This required me to manually configure libraries like retrofit to use a proxy instead of connecting directly, which has been successful but I am struggling to do the same for Fabric.

I have gone through the source code and it seems to be available on the HttpRequest class but there is no public API to access it.

Am I missing something or is it not possible at this point in time?

Please note I am not referring to the proxy settings in Android Studio. I know there are a few questions regarding that. I am interested in configuring the proxy on the connection itself.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot report through a proxy, however if you make these exceptions you can use your proxy for the rest of your traffic.

ports 80 and 443:

*.fabric.io 
*.crashlytics.com

It's important to note that we don't support IP whitelisting because we use AWS and our IPs changevery often. If you're using domains as a way of obtaining IP addresses, please be aware that the IP addresses will change very frequently - potentially every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible via Fabric itself, Google-Fabric might be different though

see https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html

> On Mac, open up the Android Studio package contents in the bin/ folder called idea.vmoptions.
>
> Add these settings to your respective file or files:
>
> -Dhttps.proxyPort=your-value-here﻿
>   -Dhttps.proxyHost=your-value-here﻿﻿
>   -Dhttps.proxyUser=your-value-here
>   -Dhttps.proxyPassword=your-value-here